# Getting sender address, python

Tags: address, development, base58

Getting senders account

Say we got txid by *listtransactions*:

**"txid" : "2ca54b92338e52bbb16562dd7a91e8670d9362bb255e21fb568acc13e732b6b7"**

then

*getrawtransaction 2ca54b92338e52bbb16562dd7a91e8670d9362bb255e21fb568acc13e732b6b7*

and

*decoderawtransaction 0100000001b2314a1f3d2552d781836cbf266b558eea31fb9f6b0e6da9340ab12e8760df0b000000006b483045022100dab5b2ef5e5be67fc0421c637c60a3d21064bcc7afe69f86909d0a7f91ae99440220762ad9a1d9c20a22378136e5653c2e7134499d1ac0ed86aba883faa7fbf6753f012102f342968588796d7214e189a6fef024bad4f29e7a155c93182a8b6f579b2c1fb2ffffffff02172e0100000000001976a914dc05a2f50f5ae09df42f584f5a5582891a41665088ac2e2f4100000000001976a914380e50d59602e9f9960f893f6f2c0f6eb7791b6088ac00000000*

out of which we finally receive:

**"asm" : "3045022100dab5b2ef5e5be67fc0421c637c60a3d21064bcc7afe69f86909d0a7f91ae99440220762ad9a1d9c20a22378136e5653c2e7134499d1ac0ed86aba883faa7fbf6753f01 02f342968588796d7214e189a6fef024bad4f29e7a155c93182a8b6f579b2c1fb2"**

So far so good. Last part is publickey, if understand correctly:**02f342968588796d7214e189a6fef024bad4f29e7a155c93182a8b6f579b2c1fb2**, which can be translated to address

Then I do following in python to get senders address:
    import hashlib

```
pkey="02f342968588796d7214e189a6fef024bad4f29e7a155c93182a8b6f579b2c1fb2"

ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')

ripemd160.update(hashlib.sha256(pkey.decode('hex')).digest())
```

but ripemd160.hexdigest() returns 8cdd1b71d32e53a9fe326212281a4a99a1c093a8, and thats not what i want.

It should return valid address, and result seems a bit off to me. I think .hexdigest is wrong way to do it, should be converted to base58.

How properly convert ripemd160.digest into account address?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found solution to problem.. if someone will find it helpful, to get senders address for python:

```
import json
import bitcoinrpc
conn = bitcoinrpc.connect_to_remote('username', 'password', host='127.0.0.1', port=9332)
accounts=conn.listaccounts()
for a in accounts:
        name=json.dumps(a)
        name = name[1:-1]

        #print name
        tran=conn.listtransactions(name)
        for t in tran:
            act=t
            txid=t.txid
            raw=conn.getrawtransaction(txid,0)
            dec=conn.decoderawtransaction(raw)
            vin=dec['vin'][0]['txid']
            raw=conn.getrawtransaction(vin,0)
            dec=conn.decoderawtransaction(raw)
            vout=dec['vout']
            print json.dumps(vout[0]['scriptPubKey']['addresses'])[2:-2]
```

also, in config add **txindex=1** and run **litecoind -reindex** from cmdline

Comment: props for C# snippet, inspirational.

Answer (score 3):

The bitcoin protocol doesn't really support the concept of a transaction sender.

All you can come up with is an address owned by someone who previously controlled the transaction's outputs, which however might not actually be the sender (e.g. for e-wallets) and who may not actually intend to receive anything there in the first place.

Take some time to see a [sample implementation written in C#](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib/blob/master/CoinWrapper/Services/RpcServices/RpcExtenderService/RpcExtenderService.cs#L120) (GetTransactionSenderAddress()).

Comment: aware of that, still it is interesting subject. I am aiming at similar to satoshidice system, which prolly was mentioned already 1000000000 times here

aiming at ltc, and whats i am really to do, is to implement interesting model of lottery(i am mathematic, not programmer)

however - tech stuff needs implementation, and I am puzzled here somewhat.

To be honest annoys hell out of me, since i am eager to implement math model to live, and cant get ovet this annoyance

Comment: SatoshiDice became a dead business model the minute a thousand clones popped up, but still it's a good way to get some hands-on experience with the protocol. Just keep in mind that even SatoshiDice often fails to determine the transaction's sender address. The sample code I posted above is tested and works well with fat clients (such as the `Bitcoin Core`) but it will mostly fail for thin clients and e-wallets.

Comment: I am not cloning dice, i just find moneygate usable to me.

I welcome any idea, to have one, constant, (mine) acc, where anyone at any time can transfer any ammount, provided with reply-to adress, so i can automatically cashout. Besides that i dont rip anything from satoshidice idea, have interesting own )

Comment: In this case you might want to take a closer look to the `refund address` facility introduced with the 0.9 client: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24423/transaction-refund-address

Comment: no.. developing for litecoins.
however, i think i can answer my question.

Comment: Really, the only way to reliably get a refund address is by asking one.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i guess i misunderstood your question:
You have to encode the ripemd160 to base58 as you can see [here](http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html)

```
def pubKeyToAddr(s):
  ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
  ripemd160.update(hashlib.sha256(s.decode('hex')).digest())
  return utils.base58CheckEncode(0, ripemd160.digest())
```

Anyway, you can always check [the details](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses) of how to construct address.
Aditionaly, if you want to use the [testnet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet), remember to replace the first char from 0 to 0x6F like this

```
  return utils.base58CheckEncode(0x6F, ripemd160.digest())
```