# How to implement and use BIP 70?

Tags: bitcoind, bip70-payment-protocol

I have a server running bitcoind 9.x, how can I incorporate features such as return addresses to my customers using BIP 70? I have seen the GIT repo but is it something that I have to download or is it already implemented in the bitcoind daemon I'm running?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's neither part of the Bitcoin daemon nor something you can just download. It's code you are expected to write and integrate with your web commerce application. The code in the git repository is only a sample.

See my answer  https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/24450/5757 for some further information.

Comment: thank you for your help, i have made some progress i think. so i downloaded the proto compiler and compiled this template https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0070/paymentrequest.proto, created a django view and passed it an instantiation of the payment object but it isn't working just yet. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid I know very little about protobuf or django so I can't be of much help. You could ask a new question but without seeing more of your code or something more specific than "it isn't working" it will be hard for anyone to answer. If you can narrow it to a specific issue that will help too; general "please debug my code" questions are not encouraged here.